# Inheritance class extends

Tags: class, inheritance

The class Ford extends the class Car. Which of the following expressions are legal?

```
Car x = new Car();
Ford y = new Ford();
x = y;
y = x;
y = new Car();
x = new Ford();
```

Comment: It seems like homework, and we'd need to do all the work for you.

Comment: Its an old exam paper question I'm stuck on. Thanks for taking the time to write back all the same

Answer (score 2):

These lines of code are not legal:

```
y = x;
y = new Car();
```

> So how does it work?

When you declare a variable of type `Car`, this variable can be any car (like a Ford, or a Ferrari).

But when you declare a variable of type `Ford`, this variable can be any `Ford car`, like a Ford Mustang car. But it could never be a Ferrari.

Also, this is legal:

```
Car a = new Ford();
Ford b = (Ford) a;
```

Because `a` is Car but it can be casted as a Ford because it is also a Ford.

Of course, this is not legal:

```
Car c = new Ferrari();
Ford  d = (Ford) c;
```

This code can be compiled. But you will have a ClassCastException because `c` is not a Ford.

Hope it helps